# Request textDocument/codeAction failed. error messages keep coming up in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfTW0.png)

These error messages keep showing up in vs code when I am working with either java or python. I am beginner into this world so please try to make the solution easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the root cause of these errors was having project stored in `WSL2` Ubuntu. After moving the project from Ubuntu to Windows directory structure, the errors disappeared.

As the error is very vague, hopefully this non-straightforward solution might help.